# I cannot seem to get the AMD Radeon RX480 running in 16.04 - Will this be fixed in 16.10?

Tags: drivers, 16.04, radeon, amd-graphics

Upgraded my system from an Radeon R5 - 240 to an RX-480.
I had mint installed before (17.3) and it was running fine with the R5-240. 
I installed the RX-480 and it would not boot, tried updating drivers, and no luck.
After that I installed Ubuntu 16.04 fresh installed and downloaded drivers and it still does not work - I can't even boot to the desktop, stuck in console mode.
Can anyone help?

Thanks
Andy

Comment: You need to direct this inquiry to AMD as it is a closed source driver or file a bug report against the open source driver.

Comment: The fglrx drivers work w/ 12.04 & 14.04. In 16.04 the problem's made clear in the link Ubuntu directs people to: https://tjaalton.wordpress.com/2016/03/11/no-catalystfglrx-video-driver-in-ubuntu-16-04/ So. If u want driver w/ full controls u would have to lose Radeon you bought & buy Nvidia instead (unpleasant, I know). Problem is Ubuntu 16.04 moved to "XServer 1.18" driver set. AMD has not supplied a driver working w/ XServer 1.18 yet & Ubuntu blacklisted in /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-framebuffer.conf (radeonfb), & another doc in /etc/modprobe.d/ where it could be # out, but still will not

Comment: function as driver lacks XServer 1.18 support. So, those like myself (using a Gizmo 2 SBC) cannot gain any useful control of the embedded Radeon graphics (as I cannot control it well enough). It is not blocked in the latest Debian...